# Android Layout ListView

Tags: android

I need following layout for my application:

```
<TextView/>
<ListView/>
<Button/>
```

But in this layout only ListView has a scrollbar.

I need Scrallbar for all page and don't need it for ListView. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use something like this:

```
ListView myListView = new ListView (this);

TextView myTextView = new TextView (this);
myTextView.setText ("Your text");
…       // setup whatever else you need
Button myButton = new Button (this);
…       // setup button text, callback, whatever

myListView.addHeaderView (TextView);
myListView.addFooterView (myButton);
```

With the following layout:

```
<ListView />
```

This adds a fixed view to be displayed at the top and bottom of the ListView, regardless of the contents of the ListView. See the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) for these methods.

Comment: Can I create this view from XML?

Comment: @skywa1ker, yes, of course. However, I could not see XML properties for the `headerView` and `footerView` in `ListView`, so I believe they will have to be created programmatically, or in separate XML files and then inflated manually.